# I am trying to infalte the activitymain.xml file but i don't know why adapter class is not being inflated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This my adapter class which is trying to inflate the recycler view with the video_View and the arraylist is ending up with the value 0. I have tried a lot of method to make it working but every time it is everytime not inflating the recyclerView.

Adapter class:

```
class Video_adapter(var videolist: ArrayList<String>):RecyclerView.Adapter<Video_adapter.ViewHolder>(){


    class ViewHolder(view: CardView):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val video:VideoView = view.findViewById(R.id.video)


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.video_view,parent,false) as CardView
        Log.i("OnCreateView","OnCreateViewHolder is working")
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return videolist.size
        Log.i("Video_list1",videolist.size.toString())
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var video = videolist[position]
        holder.video.setVideoURI(video.toUri())
        holder.video.setOnTouchListener( View.OnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                holder.video.start()
            }
            true
        })
    }
}
```

This is my main kotlin file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    lateinit var toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    lateinit var recycleradpter:Video_adapter
    lateinit var videolist: ArrayList<String>




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        videolist = ArrayList()
        getJson()
        Log.i("Video_list",videolist.size.toString())
        recycleradpter = Video_adapter(videolist)
        Log.i("Video_list",videolist.size.toString())
        recyclerView.adapter = recycleradpter


    }
    fun getJson(){
        val url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bikashthapa01/myvideos-android-app/master/data.json"
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        //volley request
        val request = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,Response.Listener<JSONObject>{ response ->
            try {
                val categories = response.getJSONArray("categories")
                for (i in 0 until categories.length()){
                    val category = categories.getJSONObject(i)
                    val videos = category.getJSONArray("videos")
                    for (i in 0 until videos.length()){
                        val video = videos.getJSONObject(i)
                        val source = video.getString("sources")
                        videolist.add(source)
                        Log.i("Url",source)
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Json request working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (e:JSONException){
                Log.i("error ",e.toString())

            }


        },Response.ErrorListener {error ->

            Log.i("JSon_request_error",error.toString())


        })
        Log.i("Video_list",videolist.size.toString())

        queue.add(request)
    }


}
```

I am not able to find what is wrong with the code why it is not inflating the recycler view.

Answer (score 1):

After the for loop in getJson method call
`recycleradpter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh the RecyclerView.

Comment: @SUPERADI are you getting any error? call getJson() in onCreate after setting the `recyclerView.adapter = recycleradpter`. The log ` Log.i("Video_list",videolist.size.toString())` will return zero because volley request is asynchronous.

Comment: Tried this one too nothing happened.

Comment: This is the link to the project repo. If you could help me

Comment: The link is not accessible. is it a private repo?

Comment: I have made the repo public, now you can check it out.

Comment: I have fixed the issue and please accept the pull request and accept my answer if it helps.

Comment: How did did you solved it. I was trying for at least 3 days

Comment: Check changes I have done in your code. I followed my own answers. Also the video links are of type HTTP so We have to add clearTextTraffic Tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.